# Why .net delegate assignment operator is not assigning the reference to the original delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates

Why the copyOfDelegate is a copy of the original delegate, instead of the reference copy of the original one?

```
    public class DelegateTester
    {
        public delegate void PrintDelegate();

        public PrintDelegate PrintCallback;
    }

    public class Client
    {
        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("in client");
        }
    }



   static void main()     
   {  
      DelegateTester tester = new DelegateTester();
      Client client = new Client();

      tester.PrintCallback += new DelegateTester.PrintDelegate(client.Print);
      tester.PrintCallback += new DelegateTester.PrintDelegate(client.Print);

      // copy the delegate
      DelegateTester.PrintDelegate copyOfDelegate = tester.PrintCallback;
      tester.PrintCallback -= new DelegateTester.PrintDelegate(client.Print);

      tester.PrintCallback();
      copyOfDelegate.Invoke();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe delegates are immutable, so where you have set:

```
copyOfDelegate = tester.PrintCallback;
```

And then:

```
PrintCallback -= new DelegateTester.PrintDelegate(client.Print);
```

You've actually assigned the original delegate instance to `copyOfDelegate`, and then a new delegate is created when you assign to `Printcallback` because of the immutability.

Answer (score 5):

Delegates are immutable like Strings. [Here is an article..](http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2008/05/11/delegates-are-immutable/)