# Is this a reference lost in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, delegates

I have some code like this:

```
public delegate void InputEventListener<T>(T e) where T : InputEvent;
private Dictionary<System.Type, System.Delegate> processors = new Dictionary<System.Type,System.Delegate>();

public bool RegisteEventListener<T>(InputEventListener<T> listener) where T : InputEvent
{
        System.Type tt = typeof(T);
        if(!processors.ContainsKey(tt))
        {
            InputEventListener<T> lis = new InputEventListener<T>(listener);
            processors.Add(tt, lis);
            return true;
        }

        InputEventListener<T> aaa = processors[tt] as InputEventListener<T>;
        aaa += (listener);
        //key point
        processors[tt] = aaa;   

        return true;
}
```

when i tried to add a second listeners into the processors with same type, if i don't call the key point line of:

```
processors[tt] = aaa;
```

the dictionary won't have the listener stored. but delegate should be a reference type right? when i modify the aaa, it should directy change the data in dictionary, but why do i still need this line of code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate types are reference types, yes. But like `System.String`, they are immutable. When you write code that looks to you as though you're modifying the instance, you're actually creating a new instance with the new value.

So if you have a delegate instance in your dictionary, and then write something like `aaa += (listener);`, you are creating a whole new delegate instance and assigning that to the variable `aaa`. The original delegate instance remains the one in your dictionary (or wherever...it doesn't really matter where you reference the original delegate instance, it always stays the same).

Here are a couple of other answers that relate:

[Why .net delegate assignment operator is not assigning the reference to the original delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6340354/3538012)
[If delegates are immutable, why can I do things like x += y?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7043883/3538012)

Comment: I added a couple of related articles which might make it even clearer